# disposing of BindingSources take up to 10 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to debug an issue with a `DataGridView` that get disposed

there is 7 column mapped as `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` which BindingSource

each combobox contains between 7 to 25 items

the grid contains about ~10k rows

the moment that I run this empty loop;

```
foreach(var row in grid.rows)
{
}
```

there is a weird thing going on with the BindingSource, the property Events (using a watch windows) get populated by over 30,000 events which will call `DataGridViewComboBoxCell.DataSource_Disposed`

is there a way to clear that list of event (without using reflection) or how to handle this situation?

Comment: The empty loop probably is causing row unsharing - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9(v=vs.110).aspx - **Preventing Rows from Becoming Unshared** section first bullet

Comment: What about unbinding your datagridview by settings its DataSource to null prior disposing it ?